# Is there anyway to wrap my entire project in one component while using expo router v2

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo, realm

I'm using realmDB and I need to wrap all of my components in a RealmProvider component, is there anyway I can do this while using expo router?

I tried this:

```
  return (
    <RealmProvider>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Stack.Screen options={{title: 'Home'}}/>
        <DeckComponent name='amONGUS' cards={50}/>
        <Modal
          transparent={true}
          animationType="fade"
          visible={isVisible}
          onRequestClose={() => {changeVisible(false)}}
        
        >
          <EnterModal name={deckName} changeName={setDeckName} submitEdit={() =>{
            console.log(deckName)
            setIsVisible(false)
          }}/>
        </Modal>
        <View style={styles.bottom}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>{changeVisible(true)}} style={styles.add} ><AntDesign name="plus" size={30}/></TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      
      </View>
    </RealmProvider>
  );
```

while using the useRealm hook in the same file and it gave me this error:
'Realm context not found. Did you use useRealm() within a RealmProvider'

Answer (score 0):

That's because how it's used, that provider only affects to it's childs, to use it globally just do that in the root _layout and will work as espected.

More details in the docs https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/root-layout/